# Resize an existing LVM partition and add the space to another LVM partition

Tags: partition, lvm

I'd like to resize an existing LVM partition and add the space to another LVM partition.

```
[root@dckapstaging ~]# df -h
Filesystem                           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_root   50G   50G     0 100% /
tmpfs                                3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                            485M   91M  369M  20% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_home  215G   93G  111G  46% /home
```

I want `/dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_root` to be extended to another 15 GB from `/dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_home`; how can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your volume group is already full, and you cannot extend it further, you will need to:

1. Shrink the filesystem in `lv_home` using the specific tools for your filesystem, e.g. `resize2fs` if you use ext3/4.
2. Resize `lv_home` accordingly with `lvreduce`.
3. Increase `lv_root` with `lvresize`.
4. Increase the filesystem in `lv_root` so that it uses all the additional space in the LV.

As always, back up your data first, resizing filesystems is always a risky business.

If you happen to use XFS in `lv_home` you'll need to use a different approach, because XFS does not support shrinking. In this case:

1. backup the data in `lv_home`
2. reduce `lv_home` with `lvreduce` (FS is destroyed at this point!)
3. recreate the filesystem in `lv_home` with smaller size
4. restore the data
5. increase `lv_root` as per steps 3 & 4 above.

Comment: For ext2/ext3/ext4, `lv_home` needs to be unmounted before shrinking. Enlarging the volume can be done while it's mounted.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you want to **unmount the partitions** in question. Boot an usb stick or similar. Backing up important data is always recommended before fiddling with filesystems.

Reduce the filesystem first in `/dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_home`. Otherwise, resizing the lv will drop the data. The way to do it depends naturally from filesystem. `resize2fs` works for ext2/3/4 filesystems. `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_home 200G`

After you've shrunken the filesystem, run `lvresize -L -15G /dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_home` to free up the 15GBs and `lvresize -L +15G /dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_root` to enlargen the `lv_root`

Finalize with your fs resize tool. For ext that'd be `resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_root` to enlarge it to maximum available space.

EDIT:corrected a typo: partition -> filesystem

Comment: resize2fs *before* lvresize ? (just a question, I never did it). BTW there is a typo 200G instead of 20G.

Comment: @Archemar `resize2fs` first because lvresize doesn't check whether reduced part contains data i.e. it's filesystem agnostic. `resize2fs` (or filesystem equivalent) does. 200G isn't a typo, `resize2fs` takes new size instead of relative size. Or my version does, at any rate.  215G - 15G = 200G

Comment: @WhimsicalWombat resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_home 200G doesnt work after unmount gives resize2fs invalid new size

Comment: @Danny That's weird. You're using ext2/3/4 filesystem, right? Check your `resize2fs` manpage to be certain that your version accepts the G-suffix. If that's not it then... I don't know. Sounds like a syntax error but the command you wrote seems to be ok. Double check for typos I guess.

Comment: When shrinking, you need to shrink the filesystem before the volume. But when enlarging, you need to enlarge the volume before the filesystem.

Comment: @Gilles Is that not what I wrote in my answer?

Comment: @Giles I can see on the man page it accepts G option in size btw I am on centos 6.5

Answer (score 0):

This is a risky operation

1. you should try to clean `/` (have a look at `/var/log` `/var/spool` and delete old and big file)
2. theorical way to proceed include

   ```
   fsck -F /dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_home
   lvresize --size -15G /dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_home
   resize2fs /home
   lvresize --size +15G /dev/mapper/vg_dckapstaging-lv_root
   resize2fs /
   ```
3. Disclaimer

   3.1. be sure to have a valid backup !!

   3.2. If this is a production system, please do try to test it before.

Comment: There's a big problem with your commands: with `lv_home`, you're shrinking the container before shrinking the content! That will break the content. Also the argument to `resize2fs` must be the volume names, not directories (and you need to unmount before shrinking).