# Linux - Increase volume of drive

Tags: centos, command-line, lvm

Running `df -h` gives me the following:

```
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root           50G   49G  1.3G  98% /
devtmpfs                         7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            7.8G  769M  7.1G  10% /run
tmpfs                            7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-home           78G  182M   78G   1% /home
/dev/sda1                        497M  338M  160M  68% /boot
tmpfs                            1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

I want to allocate more spare to `/dev/mapper/centos-root`, by reducing the allocation for `/dev/mapper/centos-home`

How would I remove 50GB from home and give it to root?

---

### Further Info

Running `mount` tells me the following:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-home on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Does this mean it's the XFS filesystem? When I run `resize2fs` I get the following error:

```
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/centos/home Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Comment: That depends entirely on how CentOS manages its device mapping, which is *probably* LVM...

Comment: It can be done.  I would not take so much, maybe only 20GB. You have to umount home, shrink the filesystem, than LVM, and then you can add it to root online.

Comment: Look into the "vgextend" and "vgreduce" commands. Make sure that a resize of the filesystem is done BEFORE the reduce and AFTER the extend with something like "resize2fs" (depends on your file system type)

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added some further info (at the bottom of the question), I think its an xfs file system?

Comment: @RamanSailopal I don't think the OP would want to change the size of the volume. More likely it's a use case for `lvresize`.

Comment: @Lee you appear to be using two different accounts (confusingly both named `Lee`). [If you want them merged please contact the moderators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: roaima is correct with the emphasis on lvresize and not vgextend/reduce (apologies) The same logic still applies in terms of resizing the file system though. If your file system is indeed XFS, use "fsadm"

Comment: XFS filesystems cannot be shrunk

Comment: @Fox agreed. It's also clearly stated in the [current best answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215641/100397) on my proposed duplicate. The suggestion there for XFS is backup-resize-restore.

Answer (score 1):

First, run `vgs` as root and check the displayed VFree value of the `centos` volume group. If it is non-zero, you have unallocated capacity in the VG: it can be used to extend the root filesystem without first shrinking `/home`. If so, you can jump straight into the last paragraph of this answer.

But if `vgs` reports that VFree is zero for the `centos` VG, read on...

Since your `/home` filesystem apparently contains only 182M of data, you could easily backup its contents to some temporary location (even an USB stick), then unmount the `/home` filesystem, then destructively resize the logical volume and recreate the filesystem.

XFS filesystems can be on-line extended, but not reduced. Therefore it would be useful to resize your `/home` LV to as small as practical, since you can then re-extend it as necessary as long as you have unallocated capacity in the volume group.

The procedure could be something like this:

```
# cd /
# tar --acls --selinux --xattrs jcvf /some/where/home_archive.tar.bz2 home
<verify that the resulting archive is readable and intact>
# umount /home
# lvreduce -L 10G /dev/mapper/centos-home
# mkfs.xfs -f /dev/mapper/centos-home    # WARNING: this will definitely destroy existing contents!
# mount /home
# cd /
# tar --acls --selinux --xattrs xvf /some/where/home_archive.tar.bz2
```

Now the `/home` filesystem is only 10G in size, and the remaining capacity is free in the `centos` volume group. You can see this with the `vgs` command.

To on-line extend the root filesystem (or any XFS filesystem located on a LVM logical volume), the procedure is:

```
# lvextend -L <new size> /dev/mapper/centos-root  # lvextend wants the LV device name
# xfs_growfs /   # xfs_growfs wants the filesystem mount-point as argument
```